# How to JQuery PHP AJAX filter based on multiple checkbox product

Tags: ajax

I am working on a job site on which jobs will have categories titles like, salary, Sector, Location etc. The idea is to enable a visitor to filter out posts by selecting appropriate checkboxes for all these three categories and show the posts which contains category parameters chosen by the user. Here is an example of what i am looking for : http://underwearking.nl/heren/ (see the left sidebar)

I have gone through over 200 plugins and searched wordpress thoroughly but i am unable to find any plugin which fulfills this. Also, I don't know much about coding but i know that it involves something like integration of jQuery Ajax and checkboxes... Can someone please help me???

Comment: what are we supposed to do with this?...

Comment: use union or union all

Answer (score 0):

Try `UNION ALL`:::

```
select distinct wp_usermeta.user_id, wp_users.user_nicename
FROM wp_usermeta
LEFT JOIN wp_users
ON wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_usermeta.user_id
UNION ALL 
select distinct t1.user_id ,t2.meta_value shop from wp_usermeta as t1, wp_usermeta as t2 where t1.user_id = t2.user_id and (  (t1.meta_key = 'category' and t1.meta_value like '%$catid%')  ) and t2.meta_key='shop_name'  order by t2.meta_value ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can an extra `JOIN` to that table `p_usermeta` in the same query, then `LEFT JOIN` the `wp_users` the same way you did, something like this:

```
SELECT distinct 
  t1.user_id, 
  wp_users.user_nicename,
  t2.meta_value shop 
FROM wp_usermeta AS t1
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON t1.user_id = wp_users.ID
where ((t1.meta_key = 'category' and t1.meta_value like '%$catid%')) 
  and t2.meta_key='shop_name'  
ORDER BY wp_usermeta.user_id, t2.meta_value
LIMIT 1,10"
```